# Unable to get protocol setup correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get a protocol working but having some issues.

**my protocol class.h**

```
@protocol FormViewDelegate <NSObject>
// sent when the user selects a row in the recent searches list
@required
- (void)getDirections:(NSString*)address :(NSString*)cityStateZip;


@end


@interface BaseFormViewController : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<FormViewDelegate> delegate;


@end
```

**my viewcontroller.h**

```
#import "BaseFormViewController.h"

@interface ViewController1 : <FormViewDelegate>
```

**my viewcontroller.m**

```
@implementation ViewController1
{
    BaseFormViewController *baseProtocol;
}

- (IBAction)getDirections:(id)sender {

    [baseProtocol getDirections:self.address.text :self.cityStateZip.text];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    baseProtocol = [[BaseFormViewController alloc]init];
    baseProtocol.delegate = self;
    ...
}
```

I am getting a compiler error stating: No visible @interface for 'BaseFormViewController' declares selector 'getDirections::'  what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I will do it like that:

```
@protocol FormViewDelegate <NSObject>
// sent when the user selects a row in the recent searches list
@required
- (void)getDirections:(NSString*)address :(NSString*)cityStateZip;
@end
```

then your view controller.h

```
@interface ViewController1 : <FormViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<FormViewDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

and then your view controller

```
@implementation ViewController1

@synthesize delegate

- (IBAction)getDirections:(id)sender {

    [baseProtocol getDirections:self.address.text :self.cityStateZip.text];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    baseProtocol = [[BaseFormViewController alloc]init];
    baseProtocol.delegate = self;
    ...
}
```

That way your view controller implement the protocol itself

hope it help

Answer (score 0):

`ViewController1` needs to implement the required methods since you stated that it conforms to the `FormViewDelegate` protocol.

```
@implementation ViewController1

- (void)getDirections:(NSString*)address :(NSString*)cityStateZip 
{
// your implementation
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here since you have written under @required tag then you must have to write defination for that method otherwise it will Give you warning which is you are getting.

You can write method under Two Tags.
1) @required : in this tag which are all methods you are declaring you must have to specify in you class.

2)@optional : in this Tag which are all methods you are declaring that are all optional methods if you dont write also you dont get warnings.

Comment: Where I have at required or not I still get a build error

Answer (score 0):

It's that simple. `BaseFormViewController` is not conforming to `FormViewDelegate` - so it have no knowledge about this method:

`- (void)getDirections:(NSString*)address :(NSString*)cityStateZip;`

If you want to pass that method to `BaseFormViewController` than make it conform to `FormViewDelegate`. And (optionally) move delegate property from `BaseFormViewController` to `ViewController1`.